# What is the difference between the Response object and Request object?

Tags: asp-classic

What is the difference between the Response object and Request object in ASP?

Comment: Is this the question you have to answer (re homework)? Do you expect anyone to do your homework for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the request object is going to hold information about the current user request, that is the client browser requesting a webpage from your server. The response object contains the response data that will be sent back to the user. Think of it in terms of a http request/response cycle. The objects hold the respective data.

Comment: Request is received by the server, Response is sent.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP Request object is used to get information from a visitor. 
Usually, you read the contents of the request to determine the course of action and the proper response.

The ASP Response object is used to send output to the user from the server.

Answer (score 0):

**Request Object:** is used to read the data submitted by the client (i.e. the data comes with the client request)

**Response Object:** is used to send instructions to the client browser.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you further.
Request object: from client (you) to server.
Response object: from Server to client (you) rendering back to the service.
These objects are called intrinsic object of ASP.Net.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why do you provide an answer that provides less details than already existing answers? As a new user don't waste your time and focus on new questions or answers for yet unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Request Object**:
     Used to send information to the clients.
**Response Object**:
     Used to retrieve information included with the request from server.